# Butterworth Filter Using Scipy

Tags: python, filtering, jupyter-notebook

I have a question about the following parameters regarding the scipy.signal.butter function. I am using python and running it in jupyter notebook.

Link for the documentation below:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.butter.html

I'm trying to implement a low pass nth order butterworth filter. And I'm confused about the parameter Wn. If I have a sampling frequency of let's say 1000Hz. And I would like to cut off frequencies above 250Hz. From my understanding of the documentation, Wn would have to be the following:

fs = 1000 * 2pi

fc = 250 * 2pi

Wn = fc/(fs/2)

Is this correct? I used the following process above, and my response did not seem accurate. But I don't have any expectation of the output so it could be right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cutoff frequencies in this method are normalized by the Nyquist frequency. (The highest resolvable frequency in the signal.) The Nyquist frequency is, by definition, half the sampling rate of the signal. In your case, that's 500Hz. So you should have `Wn = 0.5`, which comes from:

```
cutoff = 250.0
Fs = 1000.0
Wn = cutoff / (Fs / 2.0)
```

I think your confusion about radians comes from the documentation. It's not saying that you need to somehow convert your frequencies into radians. The Nyquist frequency *equals* pi radians per sample, and the sampling rate *equals* 2*pi radians per sample. This is called "half-cycles per sample". See the Wikipedia page on [Normalized frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_frequency_(unit)), which has more information.

Comment: Ok. I understand now. Thank you for the response!